# Get direction of mouse drag unity3d C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, draggable

I am making a unity 2d game wherein I want a car to be a draggable object along a curvy road. I have added the following script to the car which works for forward drag only. **How can I detect whether user is draging in forward or backward direction inside mouseDrag event?** I am new to unity and I prefer using only C# and not js.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]

public class TouchInput : MonoBehaviour {
private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;
public float speed = 20.0f;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start(){
rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void OnMouseDown(){

}

void OnMouseDrag(){
Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
rb.velocity = new Vector3(150 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use OnMouseDown() to get initial point after on drag you can find direction with using initialPoint. You can read [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DirectionDistanceFromOneObjectToAnother.html).

Comment: I thought of this but what if user drags to the left and then drags to the right without taking his finger up?

Comment: You can calculate it. In [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDrag.html): OnMouseDrag is called every frame while the mouse is down.

Comment: Please support your answer with a piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this](http://gamedevelopertips.com/how-detect-swipe-direction-unity/) simple tutorial wich is basically 7 lines of code and works like a charm. Easy and simple. You just have to use the build in Unity event system instead to write long and useless code.
**No need to use an update or fixed update.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this (Direction Algorithm is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DirectionDistanceFromOneObjectToAnother.html)):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]
public class TouchInput : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 initialPosition;
    private Vector3 offset;
    public float speed = 20.0f;

    Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 initialPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
        Vector3 heading = cursorPosition - initialPosition;
        Vector3 direction = heading / heading.magnitude; // heading magnitude = distance 
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(150 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        //Do what you want.
        //if you want to drag object on only swipe gesture comment below. Otherwise:
        initialPosition = cursorPosition;
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```